# How to combine Twitter Bootstrap 3 and HTML5 semantic elements?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use **Twitter Bootstrap 3**, but at the same time I'd like to use **HTML5 semantic elements** eg. `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<article>`, but I am confused as Twitter Bootstrap's documentation doesn't have examples for these. Is there a good practice for this?

Should my code should be something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <aside>...</aside>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10>
        <section>...</section>
    </div?
</div>
```

or maybe this:

```
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-2">...</aside>
    <section class="col-md-10">...</section>
</div>
```

or is there a better way of applying semantic elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do both ways, or even:

```
<div class="row">
    <aside>
        <div class="col-md-2">...</div>
    </aside>

</div>
```

I'd go with:

```
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-2">...</aside>
    <section class="col-md-10">...</section>
</div>
```

All are correct syntax.

Comment: Agreed. Also make note that <section class="col-md2"> would render the same as <div class="col-md2">.

Comment: Ye i probably will use the second one. TY

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this: https://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/

A good way is to use HTML5 semantic tags, with Bootstrap Less and Mixins. Then define generic class names.

You get HTML code like this:

```
<section class="news_article">
...new article content...
</section>
```

Then use Less to add boostrap columns to "news_article", font style etc.

More useful links: 
https://coderwall.com/p/wixovg/bootstrap-without-all-the-debt